# Best way to insert, update and delete different data between two tables using joins in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, multithreading

I have a multi-threading .Net application in which multiple threads should be able to write to a single SQL table.

Here is my SQL code,

```
BEGIN TRY
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CountryId VARCHAR(25)

--inserts
SELECT * INTO #tempInsert FROM (
SELECT pc.* FROM dbo.ProductCountry_1 pc
LEFT JOIN dbo.Product p
ON p.ProductId = pc.ProductId
WHERE p.ProductId IS NULL
AND pc.CountryId = @CountryId
) AS A

INSERT INTO dbo.Product(ProductId, Name, TaxCode, ShippingCode, Source, Lang, Price_Amount, Price_Currency, EstimatedShippingDate, ShipperName, ShipperDesc, ConsigneeName, CountryId)
SELECT ProductId, 
       Name, 
       TaxCode, 
       ShippingCode, 
       Source,
       Lang,
       Price_Amount,
       Price_Currency,
       EstimatedShippingDate,
       ShipperName,
       ShipperDesc,
       ConsigneeName,
       @CountryId
FROM #tempInsert

--Updates
SELECT * INTO #tempUpdate FROM (
SELECT pc.* FROM dbo.ProductCountry_1 pc
INNER JOIN dbo.Product p
ON p.ProductId = pc.ProductId

WHERE (p.Name <> pc.Name
    OR p.TaxCode <> pc.TaxCode
    OR p.ShippingCode <> pc.ShippingCode
    OR p.Source <> pc.Source
    OR p.Lang <> pc.Lang
    OR p.Price_Amount <> pc.Price_Amount
    OR p.Price_Currency <> pc.Price_Currency
    OR p.EstimatedShippingDate <> pc.EstimatedShippingDate
    OR p.ShipperName <> pc.ShipperName
    OR p.ShipperDesc <> pc.ShipperDesc
    OR p.ConsigneeName <> pc.ConsigneeName
    )
AND pc.CountryId = @CountryId
) AS B


UPDATE p SET
    p.Name = u.Name,
    p.TaxCode = u.TaxCode,
    p.ShippingCode = u.ShippingCode,
    p.Source = u.Source,
    p.Lang = u.Lang,
    p.Price_Amount = u.Price_Amount,
    p.Price_Currency = u.Price_Currency,
    p.EstimatedShippingDate = u.EstimatedShippingDate,
    p.ShipperName = u.ShipperName,
    p.ShipperDesc = u.ShipperDesc,
    p.ConsigneeName = u.ConsigneeName
FROM dbo.Product p
INNER JOIN #tempUpdate u ON p.ProductId = pc.ProductId
WHERE p.CountryId = @CountryId

--Deletes

DELETE s FROM dbo.Product p
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductCountry_1 pc
ON p.ProductId = pc.ProductId
WHERE pc.ProductId IS NULL
AND p.CountryId = @CountryId
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX), @ErrorSeverity INT, @ErrorState INT;
SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS NVARCHAR(5)), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH
```

When multiple threads try to write to Product table at the same time, I get deadlocks. Also, how can I improve performance of update and delete (I have already used MERGE but it had worse performance than this query)

Comment: have you tried breaking this out into 3 separate procs?

Comment: I haven't but would it make a difference?

Comment: You should try to avoid using all these temp tables. That is not doing your performance any good. You are making a copy of the data into a temp table which is just slowing this down for no reason. Also I have to ask, why are you updating the Product table and then immediately deleting the rows you just updated??? You also have a lot of nonSARGable predicates. The updates section has a LOT of inequality predicates. This means a table scan and no indexing will fix that.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I will remove the temp tables from this query. I am updating or deleting rows only those that have been changed in ProductCountry table. How do I improve update query to make it sargable?

Answer (score 0):

1) Not sure whether it helps, but did you try using "exists" to check whether row does not exists in table instead of using a left join?

```
--Deletes

DELETE s FROM dbo.Product p
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductCountry_1 pc
ON p.ProductId = pc.ProductId
WHERE pc.ProductId IS NULL
AND p.CountryId = @CountryId
```

2) How many rows are you deleting? If more than 50'000 or so, I would recommend to try delete with a while loop 50'000 or so each time instead of the whole load.

3) * INTO #tempInsert is usually not a good idea. Create your temp table with a create-statement including primary key, NOT NULL's and index.